# What kind of words can be formed using the word -preneur?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary, suffixes

I  have seen many words ending with preneur like entrepreneur, intrapreneur,edupreneur,ideapreneur.

I think many word can be formed using the word -preneur. But I don't know for what kind of nouns this word can be used. Is there are special rule?

Comment: I would say the rule is not to use any of them except entrepreneur unless you want to sound like you're talking in corporate buzzwords.  (Or making a joke about corporate buzzwords.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are all recent neologisms, adapted from the word "entrepreneur".

Whether you create new ones depends on how confident you are at inventing new words.

For the examples you gave, "intrapraneur" seems fine, "edupreneur" feels clunky, and a bit of a stretch.  "Ideapreneur" feels completely wrong.

Thinking about it, here is why:
entrepreneur is made up of a preposition and a noun.
"intrapreneur" takes a prepositional prefix, "intra-" meaning within, and adds it to the root noun of entrepreneur.

"edupreneur" takes the first part of a longer word noun, "education", and uses that first part as a descriptor in the new setting.

"ideapreneur" is just two nouns, jammed together.

Answer (score -2):

These are all recently invented words, so go for any nouns you like! Preferably 2 syllables like finance-preneur, kitchen-preneur. Even better starting with e, evil-preneur, ego-preneur, entry-prenur